# Stop iframe reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, detach

Is it possible to disable/restrict iframe reloading?

the problem is: When I use jquery to detach/append iframe it reloads.

```
i = $('#i') //<iframe id="i" src="..."></iframe>
p = i.parent()
i.detach()
i.appendTo(p)
```

So, after I do i.appendTo(p), ifram's content is reloaded

Comment: Instead of detaching or appending, why don't you hide the iframe or its parent?

Comment: It can be moved to another parent. Or when I need to swap two elements.

Comment: It is the detach function that is removing element from DOM preserving only jQuery data. If you avoided jQuery, and just used appendChild method, I think you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem trying to defer ads loading. I think it is not possible to fix.

The only way that I found was to change the absolute position on css.

i.e:

```
var $i = $('#i'), $t = $('#target');
$i.css({position:'absolute',top:$t.offset().top, left:$t.offset().left});
```

Maybe you will need to add **z-index** and **size** properties too. It will depends of your design.